# Why deadlock exception in single transaction in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, transactions, deadlock, database-deadlocks

I have a table `Table_1` in SQL Server 2014. It has two columns `name, id`.

I want to run the following script in two separate connections simultaneously:

```
while 1 = 1
begin
begin try
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL Serializable; 
        begin tran

        declare @maxId int = 0
        select @maxId = MAX(Id) + 1 from [dbo].[Table_1] 
        print(@maxId)

        set identity_insert [dbo].[Table_1] on
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_1] (Id,[Name])
            VALUES (@maxId,'11')
        set identity_insert [dbo].[Table_1] off

commit tran
end try
begin catch

IF(@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
rollback tran

    print ( ERROR_MESSAGE())
    print ( ERROR_SEVERITY())
    print ( ERROR_STATE())
 
end catch 

end
```

In this script, I inserted rows in my table inside the while loop. When two instances of this script run, I got the following error:

> Transaction (Process ID 62) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

Why different transactions in different connections do not wait for each other and we got a deadlock error?

In reality, I don't use while.

I just simulate high request to database (in different process) to check consistency and also check concurrency problem.

The ambiguous part of the query is why deadlock?.

One process has two action:

```
select from Table_1
```

and

```
insert into Table_1
```

Both of them placed in single transaction and single process.
I'm anticipate timeout, but why deadlock.

What I know about deadlock is when we have two resource and two transaction, If Transaction1 locks resource1 and in the same time Transaction2 locks resource2 and they need to lock other resource(Transaction1 locks resource2 and Transaction2 locks resource1). But both of them, can't lock second resource.

In this scenario, database engine terminates one of the transaction with deadlock exception.

Comment: Can you add the deadlock report?

Comment: Thats certainly not the only cause of a deadlock... highly recommend doing some reading as its a complex subkject.